# Oracle Trigger Conditional Rows

Tags: oracle, triggers, identifier

I'am just exploring Trigger in Oracle.
I have table like this
[image]

[image]

Note : WT_ID Id is FK of Water Summary but not have constraint(not directly connected)

I want to make trigger in Temp_tank table, if there are update in Table Temp_tank, it will sum all temp_tank volume with same WT_ID then updated it to Water_summary.Water_Use. Because of bussiness requirement, not all water_summary data will update. in this example only Home A will be affected

This is MyCode

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPD_WaterUse
    AFTER UPDATE ON Temp_tank 

    DECLARE 

        temp_wat number;
        homeA_id= 1;    

    BEGIN   

        IF (WT_ID = homeA_id) THEN

            SELECT SUM(ss.Volume) INTO temp_wat
            from Temp_tank ss WHERE ss.Daytime  = DAYTIME and ss.WT_ID =homeA_id; 


    --  functionUpdate(homeA_id,Daytime,temp_wat)   ;   


        ELSE
            NULL;
        END IF;
    END;
```

/

The question is, in line

```
IF (WT_ID = homeA_id) THEN
```

when i compiled, the line is ignored because WT_ID is not identifier.
is trigger cannot accept this style of code?

Comment: I don't use FOR EACH ROW sir, so :new and :old cannot be used

Comment: Ok, then the comparison ( WT_ID = homeA_id ) also has no meaning. Isn't it? Why not remove the IF statement - you already have the condition in select. Also, you can't call the function for each WT_ID if u don't use `FOR EACH ROW`

Comment: If I remove the IF statement- if there are update to temp_tank data, eventough it is not HomeA, it will update Water_summary.Volume of HomeA.  Because of bussiness requirement, not all water_summary data will update. in this example only Home A will be affected